# Hyper Magnetism?

Tags: symptoms, diagnosis, genetics, carrier-genetic

Didn't know where to post this one but this forum seemed the most suitable. So about a year ago I've discovered that my mom can "glue" metalic spoons and forks to her hand and mechanic watches slow down on her. Didn't mind that really much though it was pretty cool, till last Friday, when I decided to try it myself. And guess what? I can too, also I can "feel" the north in my head and watches are moving around 3 times faster on my hand. Last week I've been to Golan heights in Israel and we drove between mine fields and my head hurt like crazy. Can anybody explain to me this condition and probably link some useful information?

Comment: Not a legitimate medical anomaly unfortunately, please read more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_magnetism